# Convert JSON to Table using T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the JSON Input

```
{
   "agentID":"WJ",
   "recordType":"AHL",
   "recordReference":{
      "stationCode":"ATL",
      "airlineCode":"XS",
      "recordId":"10001"
   },
   "entries":[
      {
         "bag":{
            "bagType":"22",
            "bagSize":"S",
            "category":"1"
         },
         "seqNo":"1",
         "noOfBagsGiven":"2"
      },
      {
         "bag":{
            "bagType":"23",
            "bagSize":"L",
            "category":"1"
         },
         "seqNo":"2",
         "noOfBagsGiven":"5",
         "dateBagsGiven":"2019-09-18"
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the output I am hoping to get (Tabular or de-limited)
[image]

I do not know how to loop through the child entries and here is what I have so far

```
DECLARE @JSON    VARCHAR(MAX) =
'{
   "agentID":"WJ",
   "recordType":"AHL",
   "recordReference":{
      "stationCode":"ATL",
      "airlineCode":"XS",
      "recordId":"10001"
   },
   "entries":[
      {
         "bag":{
            "bagType":"22",
            "bagSize":"S",
            "category":"1"
         },
         "seqNo":"1",
         "noOfBagsGiven":"2"
      },
      {
         "bag":{
            "bagType":"23",
            "bagSize":"L",
            "category":"1"
         },
         "seqNo":"2",
         "noOfBagsGiven":"5",
         "dateBagsGiven":"2019-09-18"
      }
   ]
}';

SELECT *
FROM   OPENJSON(@json) WITH(agent_id        VARCHAR(2)  '$.agentID'
                           ,record_type     VARCHAR(4)  '$.recordType'
                           ,station_code    VARCHAR(4)  '$.recordReference.stationCode'
                           ,airline_code    VARCHAR(4)  '$.recordReference.airlineCode'
                           ,record_id       INT         '$.recordReference.recordId'
                           ,bag_type        INT         '$.entries.bag.bagType'
                           ,bag_size        VARCHAR(2)  '$.entries.bag.bagSize'
                           ,bag_category    INT         '$.entries.bag.bagCategory'
                           ,date_bags_given DATE        '$.entries.bag.dateBagsGiven'
                           );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible approach is to use `JSON_VALUE()` (to extract a scalar value from a `JSON` string) and `OPENJSON()` (to parse the `JSON` string and get results as table):

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.agentID') AS agentID,
   JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.recordType') AS recordType,
   JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.recordReference.stationCode') AS stationCode,
   JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.recordReference.airlineCode') AS airlineCode,
   JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.recordReference.recordId') AS recordId,
   j.*
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.entries') WITH (
   bagType VARCHAR(10) '$.bag.bagType',
   bagSize VARCHAR(10) '$.bag.bagSize',
   category VARCHAR(10) '$.bag.category',
   seqNo VARCHAR(10) '$.seqNo',
   noOfBagsGiven VARCHAR(10) '$.noOfBagsGiven',
   dateBagsGiven VARCHAR(10) '$.dateBagsGiven'
) AS j
```

Comment: A very elegant solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of [`AS JSON`](http://Use%20OPENJSON%20with%20an%20Explicit%20Schema%20(SQL%20Server)) and [`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply):

```
SELECT  agent_id
       ,record_type
       ,station_code
       ,airline_code
       ,record_id
       ,bag_size
       ,bag_category
       ,date_bags_given
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH(
      agent_id        VARCHAR(2)    '$.agentID'
     ,record_type     VARCHAR(4)    '$.recordType'
     ,station_code    VARCHAR(4)    '$.recordReference.stationCode'
     ,airline_code    VARCHAR(4)    '$.recordReference.airlineCode'
     ,record_id       INT           '$.recordReference.recordId'
     ,entries         NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.entries' AS JSON
     )

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(entries) WITH (
     bag_size        VARCHAR(2)     '$.bag.bagSize'
    ,bag_category    INT            '$.bag.Category'
    ,date_bags_given DATE           '$.dateBagsGiven'
);
```

For more details, see [Solve common issues with JSON in SQL Server, OPENJSON and JSON input paragraph.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#openjson-and-json-input)

Comment: Although this puts me on the right path, the above script incorrectly returns NULL for bag_category and date_bags_given on both the records. Thanks.

Comment: @AeyJey, You get NULLs, because the `dateBagsGiven` is not *within* `bag`, so the path must be `$.dateBagsGiven`, while the `bag.category` is not a `bag.bagCategory`... Both answers are very goot (I plused both of them), but - from a technical point of view - this answer is slightly better. It will not have to parse the same string over and over, as this is necessary with repeated `JSON_VALUE()` calls...

Comment: Well, It was pretty late here and I was very tired when posting this answer, so I'm missed a thing or two. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Shnugo - Please compare output of Zhorov's and Zohar's answer and you'll see some columns are missing in Zohar's answer.

Comment: @AeyJey, It is perfectly okay, that you choose the answer you like most. That said: SO is not a *write-my-code* platform, but a *show me how to do it* area. That said: From a technical point of view it is best to use a *drill-down* approach, using a combination of `AS JSON` and `APPLY OPENJSON` to dive deeper and deeper into nested objects. The answer above should give enough hints, to fix some tiny problems (typos actually) yourself... Happy Coding